# Matplotlib: Timestamp not appearing on x-axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, timestamp, axis-labels

I want to show the average 'flow' per hour over a period of 24 hours (data was collected every minute over several weeks). My current code does not produce the the timestamps on the x-axis.It's not clear to me why that is the case.

The dataset looks like this:

time____________flow_______maneuver_____time_c

15420226756.751___0.0__________1_______12:45:56

15420227756.761__ 0.1__________2_______13:45:56

15420228756.771___0.2__________3_______14:40:30

15420229756.781___0.5__________1_______15:30:20

15420230756.791___0.6__________2_______15:57:00

```
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

flow_1810['time_c'] = pd.to_datetime(flow_1810['time'],unit='s').apply(lambda x: str(str(x).split(' ')[1]).split('.')[0])

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,7))
flow_1810.groupby(['time_c','maneuver']).median()['flow'].unstack().plot(ax=ax)

# beautify the x-labels
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
myFmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M')
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(myFmt)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.HourLocator(byhour=range(0,24,3)))
```

This is the result: 
[image]

This is the format of the timestamp: (int64)

[image]

Comment: What is `mdates`? I suspect it's a problem with the date format. Can you make a  Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as it will help people answer.

Comment: @EdSmith, I've updated my question.

Comment: Hey sos.cott, can you share the sample file or the original to perform this?

Comment: @AmitAmola, sure, here's a google sheet link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1O47o-2bv7AJ1jb4Futt7s7tzb_BVqAGKJJOLzXgkWu4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you tell me in which format your datetime values have been saved here in the file?

I am not able to do a datetime conversion without knowing the time format.

Comment: And one more issue, the file you have shared, either the format has changed or I have no idea what, the same code isn't giving me anything. It's flagging an error in the to_datetime conversion itself. So can you just send me original time values. I believe there's been some change made to that.

Comment: Hi @AmitAmola thanks for taking the time. unfortunately I cannot provide the original file as it contains sensitive information. The datetime values is just an unix timestamp. However the unix timestamp is the same as the original dataset.

Comment: See scott, the issue is that I am able to convert the date values into timestamp but the values you've given in the file you've shared are converting them into 2458-01-26 04:45:56, and half of the values are resulting to this only and the other half 2458-01-26 04:45:57, so what can I plot with this mate? So I understand you can't provide the actual data, understandable, but can you just send the actual dates, not all but some. Coz I've tried every single way I can interpret these dates but to no avail. Seems like these values are too ambiguous and doesn't mean anything.
Are you getting me?

Comment: @AmitAmola I've updated the timestamps now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186309/discussion-between-amit-amola-and-sos-cott).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

df=pd.read_csv('newdata2.csv')
df.time=df.time.apply(lambda x:x.replace(',',''))
df['time_c'] = df['time'].apply(lambda x:datetime.utcfromtimestamp(float(x)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H'))
df.time_c=pd.to_datetime(df.time_c, format='%Y-%m-%d-%H')

df.groupby(by=['time_c']).flow.sum().plot(figsize=(14,8))
```

Let me know if it's working or not.

Comment: This example only returns the date and not the hour.

Comment: It has hour attached to it sos.cott. It's a datetime type index. Did you plot your values via the above code?